Using kong ingress controller before rancher
I've a home setup where Kong Ingress Controller is installed. After that I installed Rancher without the need of rancher-ingress.
There are many example of installing Rancher first then Kong Ingress, but I just wanted to try a different approach.
This is the helm command to install Rancher:
helm install rancher rancher-latest/rancher \
  --namespace cattle-system \
  --set hostname=rancher.homek3s.com \
  --set bootstrapPassword=xxx\
  --set ingress.enabled=false

Over at bottom image, I can see that rancher installation have created a service on port 80 and 443. How should I expose this using Kong Ingress Controller?

Thanks much!
